# ラベルにToolTipを設定しようとするとVisualStudioがフリーズする

Tags: c#, visual-studio

お世話になります。

VisualStudio2019CommunityでのC#(Windowsフォームアプリケーション)でデザイン中のフォームの中に適当にラベルを配置し、その後、フォームの中にToolTipを配置し、ラベルのプロパティで『toolTip1のToolTip』右側のプルダウンを開き、そのまま何も入力せずにほかの部分をクリックして入力窓を閉じると、フォームの編集画面が点滅してVisualStudioがフリーズします。

これはVSの不具合なのでしょうか？

対処方法をご存知の方おりましたらご助力いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ラベルだけでなく、ボタンなどでも同じ現象が起きます。

Comment: ウチの VS2019Pro は Ver 16.2.3 ですが、１００％ではないですが再現しました。　まあハングアップするのは不具合でしょうが SO に書いても仕方ないのでは。書き込むなら MSDN Forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/home/ のほうが適切っぽい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、MSDNのほうに投稿しました。マルチポストになる可能性もありますが、『こういうことがあった』ということでスレッドは残そうかと思います。削除したほうが良い場合はご指摘ください。

Comment: 解決できるのが望ましいですが、(現時点では)不具合らしいという情報でもまとめれば回答になりうると思います。コメントでのやり取りも踏まえて投稿してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ほぼ解決例となる回答もいただけているようですので、ここに書き込みをしたのも無駄ではなかったみたいです。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/39c32519-d59d-4d39-b77a-8bce04667f7c/c?forum=netfxgeneralja
では再現しないとありましたが、ウチでは Ver 16.2.3 で再現しています。１回クリックしただけではなかなか再現しませんが、数回試してみたり ALT+TAB したりといろいろやっているとロック状態になり再現します。その後 Visual Studio 自体が自己クラッシュ検出したりしなかったりといろいろ厄介そうです。

次のように preview バージョンでは修正済みとのこと
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/663945/visual-studio-freezes-when-changing-winform-object.html
今、この不具合で困っているなら preview バージョンにしてみてもよさそう。
製品版に反映されるまで待つのもよし、でしょう。

---

2019/Sep/06 追記
Visual Studio 2019 Professional Version 16.2.4 でバグ再現しました

---

2019/Sep/11 追記
Visual Studio 2019 Professional Version 16.2.5 で再現困難。修正済みと考えてよさそう。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.5
には「エディターの使用量の延長後に発生する UI のフリーズを修正します」とありますが日本語が意味不明。英語に切り替えると 「 Fixed UI freezes occurring after extended usage of the editor. 」となり、これもかなり意味不明ですが extended usage ってのが△ボタンを押して拡張メニューを開いたらってことだと解釈するとこれっぽいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私も16.2.3ですが、私の場合は100%確実に発生します。しかも、コメントに追加したとおり、ボタンなどでも同様に発生してしまい、『そもそもToolTipは使えない』といった感じになってしまっています。今のところ、使わないほうが無難だとして使わないようにしているので、バージョンアップまで待ちながら使い続けていくことにします。

Comment: 自己レスです。私もバージョンを16.2.4に上げたら、ますますフリーズの程度が多くなりました。しかも、ラベルの設定でも出ました。多分これはVisualStudioのテキスト入力のプルダウンの中に何かしらの不具合が入っている感じです。素人判断ですが。

Comment: 自己レスです。16.2.5で修復された模様です。いろいろありがとうございました。